# Pull-up resistor causing unintentional voltage divider?

Tags: voltage-divider, comparator, feedback, pullup, schmitt-trigger

[image: Comparator and schmitt trigger]

I'm trying to use the output of a comparator as the input of a schmitt trigger built with positive feedback on another comparator. Both have open collector outputs. When the two are not connected, each individually works exactly as I expect them to. When I connect the two, neither seems to function properly. I don't get expected outputs from the comparator or the schmitt trigger. There's more to it than that, but I've tracked down the unexpected behaviour to just this tiny portion of the circuit. I suspect that the pull-ups are causing an unintentional voltage divider that is messing up the signal between them.

If these were devices with push-pull outputs and the pull-ups were omitted, then it looks right doesn't it? Or is there something I am totally missing?

If the pull-ups are interfering, then I guess the solution would be to interpose a voltage follower or dual-supply buffer between them. Is there any other method I could use or does that make sense?

Thank much!

Comment: What values are your resistors? Are the pullups at all close in value to the others?

Comment: And what are the chips and the supply voltages? Don't hold back, Rory. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: "I don't get expected outputs from the comparator or the schmitt trigger"..... hmmmm...... Doctor, doctor there's something wrong with me - can you prescribe some pills.... now what is missing that prevents the doctor prescribing the correct or indeed any pill. There are two important things that you have omitted to say and I don't mean please or thankyou in advance.

Comment: The purpose of the Schmitt trigger usually is to provide hysteresis and reduce chatter when threshold-comparing an analog signal.  The comparator doesn't have the hysteresis, and its output will be: (1) digital high/low, (2) possibly with chatter.  It would defeat the purpose of the Schmitt trigger.  Is there a reason why the comparator is upstream of the Schmitt trigger?

Comment: I don't have it directly in front of me so I'm going on memory for some of the resistor values. The chips are LM319's, the pull-ups are 2K. If I recall correctly the feedback resistor is 20K and the input resistor is 4.7K. The goal for the schmitt trigger was to get threshold voltages of about 1V and -1V (precision isn't too critical). With a 4.7k and a 20K resistor that should make the thresholds about 0.9V and -0.9V. The full circuit will include more schmitt triggers with different thresholds and more comparators with different output voltages but I need to understand this problem first.

Comment: Schmitt trigger makes sense when its input is an analog voltage.  In this case, the input to Schmitt trigger is the output of the comparator which is digital: either -5V, or +5V, never in between.  In such situation, the hysteresis becomes inconsequential.

Comment: I know, purely for the picture given above. But ultimately there will be more comparators and more schmitt triggers all with different thresholds and such. In that case this schmitt trigger might also get a 0V input in which case it should maintain it's current state. Before I get into the greater complexity of switching or multiplexing more inputs, I need to understand why a single input doesn't work.

Comment: If the output of your comparator gets pulled down to (almost) -5V, and the reference voltage for the Schmitt trigger is (exactly) -5V, then won't the Schmitt trigger always be in the same state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. All I did was add a voltage follower with a push-pull output between them and it started behaving as expected. Adam Haun was right on the reference voltage; it was incorrectly set to -5 in the schematic but is actually connected to ground.

I guess the helpful Schmitt trigger calculators you find online just assume you are using push-pull outputs because the calculations are incorrect when you factor in a pull-up on the output.